# Error CS0104: 'Guid' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Guid' and 'System.Guid'

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

On one of my projects I have enabled ImplicitUsings (C# 10) feature. The project is an Sdk project multi-targeting .NET 4.8 Framework and .NET 6. As of yesterday my builds started failing on Azure DevOps with the following error:

> Error CS0104: 'Guid' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Guid' and 'System.Guid'

Even a build of a previously known-good commit (day before yesterday) is now failing. The pipeline hasn't changed. Inspecting the agent's image yields the same version (20220207.1). The problem doesn't reproduce locally on the latest Visual Studio 2022 (17.1).

The problem occurs in files that include `using System`, such as EF Core migration files. I probably could resolve the problem by removing these "unused" usings, but the problem will reappear whenever a new migration is created. The generated usings (`obj\Debug\net48\Project.GlobalUsings.g.cs`) declare the following using `global using global::System;`. Using `Guid` in other files don't produce this error.

Update. The saga continues. I'm now also getting a build failure on a .NET 6 project referencing other .NET Standard 2 projects. The error lies in a generated source file (DragonFruit) with the line `using System.Threading.Tasks`. Builds fine locally, but fails on Azure DevOps with this error:

> D:\a\1\s\XXX\obj\Debug\net6.0\XXX.g.cs(8,31): error CS0104: 'Task<>' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' and 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' [D:\a\1\s\Source\XXX.csproj]

What could've changed that these usings are now causing build failures? And how can I resolve this warning without having the manually update the migrations?

Comment: Have you tried disabling implicit usings? Looks like they're somwhat causing the confusion. (Why this only happened as of yesterday, I don't know, though).

Comment: I'd need to reintroduce all implicit usings (make them explicit). Not something I fancy doing. Also I don't know why I would want to try that. I'm trying to figure out was caused this breakage and how to resolve it (if possible).

Comment: Can you see which build is causing the issue, Net4.8 or Net6.0? This _is_ a weird thing, anyway, because `System.Guid` is always in a system dll and cannot come from a (potentially conflicting) reference.

Comment: For the multi-target build the .NET 4.8 build failed and .NET 6.0 succeeded. However another project that only targets .NET 6.0 has a similar build failure: `error CS0104: 'Task<>' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' and 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'`

Comment: Do you have any `<Reference Include="..." />` entries in your project files that are active when targeting .Net6.0? These should only be used for .NET framework builds.

Comment: There are no such references, the .NET 4.8 references are conditional on the target framework: `<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net48'"><Reference Include="..." /></ItemGroup>`.

Comment: Could you please share your .csproj package references ?

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT What are you looking for? The project is not open source and I'm inclined not to share any private code here.

Comment: Some SonarCloud users have been having this problem too - https://community.sonarsource.com/t/timespan-is-an-ambiguous-reference-between-system-timespan-and-system-timespan/59245

Comment: possibly related to https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/59564

Comment: @AndreiEpureishiring I don't think it is related. That issue is having to do with resolving ambiguity in types between namespaces. This is an apparent ambiguity in the of the same type in the same namespace.

Comment: @LeoD interesting, this only happens with our Sonar build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posted on the Sonar Community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/timespan-is-an-ambiguous-reference-between-system-timespan-and-system-timespan/59245/15):

> FYI for those not following the Roslyn bug [#60259](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/60259), Microsoft have identified [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/60259#issuecomment-1167754662) in the compiler that could cause the observed behaviour in some multi-threaded scenarios.
>
> Update: ... and the issue has been fixed. The fix is currently linked to the v17.3 release i.e. it is not yet available.

So Visual Studio 17.3 (and related tooling) will contain a fix for this.

Update: since updating to 17.3 I haven’t seen this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It can be bypassed removing unnecessary `using` statements, in all your files.
See: [removing unnecessary using statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cMOy.png).

For some reason, the SonarCloud extension is adding this unexpected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Agree with Adrian and Wiliam...

The ambiguous references seems to be a result of a compiler bug or feature which gets confused when implicit using and unnecessary usings statements are used.  May work for you, certain did for us.

SDK               Default namespaces
Microsoft.NET.Sdk

- System
- System.Collections.Generic
- System.IO
- System.Linq
- System.Net.Http
- System.Threading
- System.Threading.Tasks

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

- System.Net.Http.Json
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging